# What is the best way to get our Person into our User using spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: domain-driven-design, dao, jdbctemplate

I have two domain objects:

1. User (which has a Person)
2. Person

**FYI**: In our domain there are Persons (people :-) that are not users so we can't just combine them.

I am trying to figure out the best way of getting the Person object populated into the User object. I have come up with 3 possible solutions and was curious what others have done and any pros and cons that others can see.

**Option 1:**

Have our UserDao and PersonDao wired into our Userservice and then have `userService.getUser(userId)` call the `userDAO.getUser(userId)` then take the user we get back from that and call `user.setPerson(personDao.getPerson(user.getPersonId()))`

**Pros**: Don't have to wire in a dao inside a dao (isn't that bad...not sure)

**Cons**: Something seems wrong about having the dao return a domain object that isn't fully initialized right? Then you have to worry about whether or not there is a person in the User object. Hitting the database twice. Also you then have to add a personId to the User object instead of just having a Person object.

**Option 2:**
Have the UserDao's getUser() method join the user table with the person table and then inside the UserRowMapper setup the user and then call `user.setPerson(personRowMapper.mapRow(rs, rowNum))`

**Pros**: Don't have to wire in a dao inside a dao (isn't that bad...not sure). Also you only hit the database once instead of hitting the database twice in the other to options.

**Cons**: The PersonRowMapper would be its own class and not encapsulated in the PersonDao (should it be?).

**Option 3:**

Have the PersonDao wired into the UserDao and then just call `user.setPerson(personDao.getPerson(rs.getLong("person_id")));`

**Pros**: The personDao is in charge of getting the Person domain object and the userDao doesn't need to know details about how that person was retrieved.

**Cons**: The personDao is wired into the userDao (is that bad?). Hitting the database twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second option, as you pointed out hitting the database twice is costly.

I have one suggestion, shouldn't it be, User is a Person (Inheritance) rather than User has a Person (Composition)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree...and so does Marten Deinum :). http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120868-What-is-the-best-way-to-get-our-Person-into-our-User-using-spring-jdbcTemplate&p=395709#post395709. As for the User is a Person, in most scenarios that is correct but with what we are doing its not necessarily the case. Thanks again!